# How to solve "GPU Lockup - switching to software fbcon" on new install of 12.10-desktop-amd64

Tags: nvidia, 12.10, software-installation, 64-bit

Error occurs during startup of Ubuntu Installation. Sometimes I'll get to the Welcome screen [just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz0eG.png), the screen will just glitch out, or will simply freeze during the loading icon.

- nvidia GTS 250
- Intel Core i7 920
- 9 GB Memory

I was able to install 12.04.1, but after performing upgrade to 12.10 it get the same problem on startup; glitches in graphics, missing content etc. Also noticed after the upgrade, I'm no longer able to connect to internet; neither ethernet or wifi.

Answer (score 5):

Solution for me was

1. Boot using live disc.  Hold down shift to get to boot options.  You should get a menu to try Ubuntu before installing, Install to disc etc etc.
2. Hit F6 and choose `nomodeset`, then press escape.
3. Choose the boot option you want.

If you get in then you will likely need install the proprietary driver for you card.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Small problem that I ran into: You have to press [space] to activate  `nomodeset`

Comment: note that it's actually `nomodeset` (with an e) like @panmari said, not `nomodset` as in the answer. See http://askubuntu.com/a/38834/234373 for more instructions

Answer (score 3):

I simply had to install the package `nvidia-current` (proprietary drivers) as described here: http://fenon.de/absturz-von-ubuntu-mit-der-fehlermeldung-gpu-lockup/

Answer (score 2):

I've been facing this issue when trying to install Elementary OS Freya from a USB stick and the fix above didn't work. I simply couldn't get in, either I'm stuck at the Elementary logo with a cursor, black screen with a cursor which changes to GPU lockup message or sometimes both. My graphics card is an NVidia Go 7300

I managed to get it working, following this [suggestion from ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2258334.html):

> I used the `nomodeset` settings in the option under <kbd>F6</kbd> and I edited the end of the end bootline to `nouveau.modeset=0`.