# GPU lockup during Trusty Tahr 14.04 installation

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, system-installation, nouveau, lockup

I have a problem with Ubuntu 14.04 installation.

I boot up the disc, it loads, then it takes me to a white empty screen and gets stuck for a while. After that terminal opens telling that my GPU has locked up. I am aware I could resolve this by installing video drivers, but hey, I haven't even installed my Ubuntu :(

I am pretty sure it's because of my GPU (an old Nvidia 9500GT), but I'm still saving up for a new one.

I have faced a problem when installing Ubuntu 12.04 on this particular machine. It used to get stuck at some point also, but it once did not and I don't know why. I happilly installed my Pangolin back then after that lucky case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same videocard as yours, and I have experienced the same problem with the LiveCD. There is some problem with the default nouveau video driver.

When the boot screen displays a menu in the beginning (unless hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> down), press <kbd>F6</kbd> and check `nomodeset` on, then continue the boot.

Remember installing/activating "nvidia-current" later to the installed version, because nouveau fails with our videocard.

Meanwhile I have found the same problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205021/how-to-solve-gpu-lockup-switching-to-software-fbcon-on-new-install-of-12-10?rq=1).

Comment: I have skipped that answer for some reason. My Tahr is up and running. Did the F6 thing, then installed, booted directly to recovery mode, enabled network, selected root, `apt-get install nvidia-current`, `reboot` and I am now a happy person. Thanks!