# cannot login after Wednesday [1-11-17] update

Tags: 16.04, updates, login, gpu

For perhaps the last month I have had problems sometimes logging into my Ubuntu after updates. But I would shut down the computer and restart until I could successfully login, and that worked for me. After the Wednesday [1-11-2017] update, I could no longer login. When I pressed CTRL + ALT + F1, one of the lines of text said

"nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GPU lock-up - switching to software fbcon"

When I tried to login, the text console said "login incorrect"

Thankfully, I was able to login after I went into Recovery Mode.

However, I still cannot login to my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS unless I enter Recovery Mode.

(In November, 2015 my son bought a new hard-drive and installed my Ubuntu on an old Gateway computer. I don't know if that makes any difference or not. I'm  not sure where we got the graphics card.)

I like Ubuntu, but why could I login fine and then after an update not be able to login ?

Comment: Try to boot with a previous kernel using grub menu. The problem most likely is with the video driver. What is the graphics card?

Comment: My graphics card is a GeForce 8600 GT (NVIDIA).

Comment: Did you install any drivers for it? How?

Comment: I'm not sure where the driver came from. At some point in the past I had to re-seat it to make it work.  The sticking point is that everything was  working fine until Wednesday's update - with the exception that sometimes recently I had to re-start the computer to log in. I keep thinking that it had something to do with the updates. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: This may be related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/205021/how-to-solve-gpu-lockup-switching-to-software-fbcon-on-new-install-of-12-10. @Pilot6, do you think it is a good idea to attempt proprietary drivers installation if tty login is possible?

Comment: I'm sorry I got the driver and the video card mixed up. My son said that he only used whatever drivers came with the Ubuntu download. He did not install any special drivers.

Comment: @BillSchell Nvidia proprietary drivers are available for installation directly through Ubuntu package system, but open source, non-proprietary are used normally.

Comment: @BillSchell Anyway, as described [here](http://fenon.de/absturz-von-ubuntu-mit-der-fehlermeldung-gpu-lockup/), installing `nvidia-current` package may help you.  Type `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` into your terminal to install it. After it succeeds, reboot your PC and see what happens.

Comment: Thank God I am back !  I was beginning to think all hope was gone.  I installed the nvidia driver as you said. I then was in a login loop, and I could in no way possible log-in, not even from the recovery mode. I then purged all things nvidia, did the installation for desktop, and a couple other things which I don't understand. Thankfully I was then able to login from recovery mode. It's been a long day.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved :) I went to the website for the Canonical Group's "Graphic Drivers" team. The driver they recommended for my GeForce 8600 was the proprietary "nvidia-340"(340.98).

I clicked on the "System Settings" icon on the left side of my computer screen, then I clicked "Software and Updates", then "Additional Drivers".

Ubuntu automatically searched for a list of available drivers. I chose the recommended driver and pressed the button to install. Ubuntu automatically installed the driver.

Everything is good again. (At least for now.) I can log-in to my computer no problem. After three days and many hours of frustration and despair, it was almost too easy :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you somehow, but for general case it might work.

While you are in the recovery mode you can check list of existing users

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

Then, if your user exists, assuming that only the password has changed, you can attempt to change it back using:

```
passwd [your username here]
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to enter the terminal and get my user name.  My user name is a little different than what it show on the screen login page.  So then I was able to log-in in the terminal using my password

Comment: @BillSchell So you are able to login in terminal using you login and password, but you can't login to graphic environment, don't you? Then it's not login/password related problem and it may have something to do with  graphics drivers as *Pilot6* pointed out.

Comment: Once I was logged in the terminal,  I typed in CTRL+ALT+F7. That took me to the desktop. The desktop looked mostly normal, but the features were not operational. I went back to the terminal, and I think it said something about the display not working right.

Comment: @BillSchell Did you install any drivers? What does `nvidia-smi` command output for you?

Comment: My son bought a new hard-drive and put this together in November, 2015.   I don't think  we installed anything since then, except that I re-seated the video card.

Comment: "nvidia-smi: command not found"

Comment: Alright, so I suppose you don't have Nvidia drivers then, as you've just said

Comment: What did the message about display not working right say?

Comment: I don't remember.

Comment: I think it's time to try the Nvidia drivers.